# Running the magento tests from command prompt

Tags: magento2.2

[image]

Hi,
I am getting below error,while executing magento test scripts from command prompt.
Environments using:
Installed magento on xampp,windows 10 and running on chrome browser

Thanks,
kumar.

Comment: Did you try to run th test with PHP bin/magento dev:tests:run?